# Bash add to end of file (>>) if not duplicate line

Tags: bash, logging

Normally I use something like this for processes I run on my servers

```
./runEvilProcess.sh >> ./evilProcess.log
```

However I'm currently using Doxygen and it produces lots of duplicate output

Example output:

```
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
```

So you end up with a very messy log

Is there a way I can only add the line to the log file **if** the line wasn't the last one added.

A poor example (but not sure how to do in bash)

```
$previousLine = ""
$outputLine = getNextLine()
if($previousLine != $outputLine) {
  $outputLine >> logfile.log
  $previousLine = $outputLine
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the process returns duplicate lines in a row, pipe the output of your process through `uniq`:

```
 $ ./t.sh 
one
one
two
two
two
one
one
 $ ./t.sh | uniq
one
two
one
```

If the logs are sent to the standard error stream, you'll need to redirect that too:

```
 $ ./yourprog 2>&1 | uniq >> logfile
```

(This won't help if the duplicates come from multiple runs of the program - but then you can pipe your log file through `uniq` when reviewing it.)

Comment: Tried and this didn't help, still get loads posted to the console

Comment: You don't say anything about stuff posted to the console in your question. If the errors aren't redirected to the file, you'll need to redirect stderr too  ` ... 2>&1 | uniq >> yourlog`

Comment: You're right for some reason all the debug information comes out as stderr!

Answer (score 3):

Create a filter script (`filter.sh`):

```
while read line; do
  if [ "$last" != "$line" ]; then
    echo $line
    last=$line
  fi  
done
```

and use it:

```
./runEvilProcess.sh | sh filter.sh >> evillog
```